# How can I solve the 424 HTTP error in Google search console when submitting a sitemap?

Tags: xml, http, sitemap, google-search-console

When I submit my sitemap, Google search console says "Couldn't fetch" and it shows a 424 HTTP error. Furthermore, when I do a Search Engine test in [XML sitemaps](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/se-bot-simulator.html), it says that URL isn't available for Google.

[image]

[image]

I can access to my sitemap through Google Chrome and other browser. AFAIK the source code in the sitemap is OK and xml-sitemaps.com doesn't detects errors in it.

[This](https://pantalonesrojos.000webhostapp.com/index.xml) is my sitemap. How can I solve the 424 error?

Answer (score 0):

In the error message provided by Google, the problem is explained

> 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' HTTP header

In the following screenshot, your sitemap is open along with the network tab in developer tools, showing the response headers of your sitemap URI. As you can see, something on your side is sending `noindex` within the `X-Robots-Tag` response header.

[image: Screenshot of network tab showing noindex as part of X-Robots-Tag header]

The purpose and meaning of this response header is to explicitly tell bots like Google Sitemaps *not* to index the requested URI. So, they're following that direction and presenting it as an error.

This could be due to web server configuration or something the application serving this file sends along.

If you can provide more information about your server/application setup, I'll be happy to assist. It would help to know what web server software you're using (IIS, Apache, etc.) and whether this is being served as a static file or via other means.